# Creating GlyphRenderers for modifying the legend

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I want to create a bokeh application that can filter points based on some attribute. Here is a very simple code example for my use case that filters points on the plot using checkboxes.

```py
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, curdoc
import bokeh.models as bmo
from bokeh.layouts import row
import numpy as np


def update_filter(selected_colors):
    keep_indices = []
    for i, color in enumerate(cds.data['color']):
        if color2idx[color] in selected_colors:
            keep_indices.append(i)
    view.filters[0] = bmo.IndexFilter(keep_indices)


cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
                                x=np.random.rand(10),
                                y=np.random.rand(10),
                                color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 
                                       'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'red'])
                      )
view = bmo.CDSView(source=cds, filters=[bmo.IndexFilter(np.arange(10))])
checkboxes = bmo.CheckboxGroup(labels=['red', 'green', 'blue'], active=[0, 1, 2])
color2idx = {'red': 0, 'green': 1, 'blue': 2}
checkboxes.on_change('active', lambda attr, old_val, new_val: update_filter(new_val))
fig = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title='Visualize')
fig.circle(x='x', y='y', fill_color='color', size=10, source=cds, view=view, legend_field='color')

curdoc().add_root(row(checkboxes, fig))
curdoc().title = 'Plot'
```

It works well, however, when I filter points out by de-selecting one of the checkboxes, the legend becomes erroneous.
Below is a screenshot when all the colors are selected:
[image: Plot when all points are visible]

And this is a screenshot when one of the colors is de-selected:
[image: Erroneous colors in the legend]

As it can be seen, the legend for "green" became red in color when the checkbox for "green" was de-selected.

I found that legends do not work properly with CDSView and it is still an unsolved issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8010

So, I wrote the function below that would modify the legend so that it is not erroneous.

```py
def update_legend():
    # Find the indices in the CDS that are visible
    filters = view.filters
    visible_indices = set(list(range(len(cds.data['x']))))
    for filter in filters:
        visible_indices = visible_indices & set(filter.indices)

    # Get a list of visible colors
    visible_colors = set([cds.data['color'][i] for i in visible_indices])
    # Create a dummy figure to obtain renderers
    dummy_figure = figure(plot_width=0, plot_height=0, title='')
    legend_items = []

    # Does not work
    for color in visible_colors:
        renderer = dummy_figure.circle(x=[0], y=[0], fill_color=color, size=10)
        legend_items.append(bmo.LegendItem(label=color, renderers=[renderer]))

    fig.legend[0].items = legend_items
```

And added another event callback for the checkbox group:

```py
checkboxes.on_change('active', lambda attr, old_val, new_val: update_legend())
```

When I did the above, the labels in the legend were corrected but now the glyphs are not rendered in the legend. Below is a screenshot of the same:
[image: Invisible Glyphs in the Legend]

What am I doing wrong? How should I create a `GlyphRenderer` for the legend such that the issue gets resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This works for Bokeh v2.1.1. In addition to your original code you can also click on a legend item to show/hide the circles.

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, Row, CDSView, IndexFilter
import numpy as np

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
cds = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=np.random.rand(10),
                            y=np.random.rand(10),
                            color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'red']))

def update_filter(selected_colors):
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        renderers[i].visible = True if i in selected_colors else False

checkboxes = CheckboxGroup(labels=colors, active=[0, 1, 2], width = 50)
checkboxes.on_change('active', lambda attr, old_val, new_val: update_filter(new_val))

fig = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title='Visualize')
views = [CDSView(source=cds, filters=[IndexFilter([i for i, x in enumerate(cds.data['color']) if x == color])]) for color in colors]
renderers = [fig.circle(x='x', y='y', fill_color='color', size=10, source=cds, view=views[i], legend=color) for i,color in enumerate(colors)]
fig.legend.click_policy = 'hide'

curdoc().add_root(Row(checkboxes, fig))
curdoc().title = 'Plot'
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! If in my application, the points also get re-colored, say, based on certain labels inside a field in the CDS, wouldn't I have to create the renderers again?